# How to fix the openCV error with cv2.CascadeClassifier?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am creating a car recognition program.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np 

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')
```

This error is being thrown:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:722: error: (-49:Unknown error code -49) Input file is empty in function 'cv::FileStorage::Impl::open'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Python\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')
SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set
```

I have cars.xml in the working directory so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: did you try different cascade classifiers, like the ones for face detection?

Comment: no yet..do you know such classifiers?

Comment: opencv should be shipped with a few of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the .xml file exists, but the contents are corrupt. I just spent way too long trying to figure this out only to realize that I didn't download the xml file properly. If you are 100% sure the file is correct, god help you.